# Websphere 7 cannot find ActionServlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I am using Webshpere 7 and my Java version is 1.6. My Struts version is 1.1. When I start my server I get the following error:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper run [Servlet Error]-[class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1682)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1673)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1581)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:936)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:857)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:292)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:722)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:607)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1162)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1313)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:938)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2092)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:380)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:928)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

I have included the struts jar and it is in my build path. My servlet is defined in `web.xml` as:

```
<servlet id="Servlet_1165231311172">
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mapping</param-name>
            <param-value>mj.cchp.actionMapping.CCHPActionMapping</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>validate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

I uninstalled the application from my server, deleted the files from the profile and tried to redeploy the application but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.j2eedt.core.internal.project.WTPEarProject.getWorkareaDirectoryPath(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.packaging.DefaultPackagerStrategy.getBuildFolder(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.packaging.DefaultPackagerStrategy.initBuildArea(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.DeploymentUtil.copyDeploymentAssemblyLibraries(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.EARDeployment.ą(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.EARDeployment.doProjectTypeSpecificPostResyncAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.Deployment.resyncAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.EARDeployment.resyncAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.Deployment.resyncAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.EARDeployment.deployAsExplodedArchive(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.Deployment.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.jobs.C.ā(Unknown Source)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.ast.deploy.core.jobs.C.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Is your struts.jar file in WEB-INF/lib or inside an enclosing EAR file somewhere?

Comment: It must be deployed, not just in your build path. Hopefully there's a good reason for running such an ancient artifact.

Comment: @SteveC The struts.jar is included in my WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @DaveNewton The struts.jar is included in my WEB-INF/lib. Shouldn't that be automatically deployed.

Answer (score 1):

There was the a problem with the EAR being created. I deleted the application, restarted the server and redeployed the application which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jar with Struts to your application. Build path is good in your development environment, but to run it must be somehow in the classpath during runtime. The easiest is as Steve C suggested - to add struts.jar to your WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: The struts.jar is included in my WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` can manifest sometimes when a dependent class is not available.

Make sure that you application has access to the dependent jars as well, such as:

- commons-beanutils
- commons-digester
- commons-logging
- etc

Comment: All of these jars are included and are present in the WEB-INF/lib folder.